# Rails generate [anything] creates project called generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This one really is perplexing me. I've just been through the railstutorial.org tutorial fairly smoothly with no issues.

I created a new app today (same environment) and called it take2. However, what appears to be happening is that any time I type in rails [anything] it just creates a new app named [anything]. For example this means I'm unable to type rails generate rspec:install

I'm using rails 3.0.

Appreciate any help you guys might have... (I'm surprised I've managed to stave away from SO this long, getting to where I am now wasn't easy!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command changed a little new projects are created with rails new "nameofproject"

You have to be within a project's folder to use rails generate for generating scaffolds and such.

Check out these tutorials for help. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Actually - I *am* in the project folder, and I am using the syntax you mention.

Comment: What does rails -v report? Do you potentially have multiple versions of rails installed? Also, can you post the output when you use "rails generate scaffold books title:string author:string" for example?

Comment: Hey - it did turn out to be that somehow, my version of rails had downgraded. Weird.